# Cumulative distribution function and indicator function

Tags: probability

I really need explanations on a problem that I've been blocked for several days.

$X$ is a random variable and its cumulative distribution function is $F_X(t)=\dfrac{1}{2} 1_{[0,1[} + (1-e^{-x})1_{[1,\infty[}$.

I have to found the cumulative distribution of $Y=X1_{[0,1[}$.

For me, we have :

$\{Y \leq t \in ]-\infty,0[ \} = \{\}$ then $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t)=0$ if $t \in ]-\infty,0[$.

$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) = 1$ if $t \in [1,\infty[$.

$\mathbb{P}(\{Y \leq t \in [0,1[ \}) = \mathbb{P}(\{X \leq t \in [0,1[ \}) = \mathbb{P}(X < 1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

But it's false. In the correction, they write that : $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) = 0$ if $t<0$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) = 1$ if $t \geq 0$. Does anyone have an explanation to help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first thing to realize would be that $Y$ as written in your question is **not well defined** since $X$ is defined on $\Omega$ and $\mathbf 1_{[0,1[}$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ hence, unless $\Omega=\mathbb R$, the formula $Y=X\mathbf 1_{[0,1[}$ makes no sense. (Oddly, the accepted answer does not even mention the fact.) Would you actually mean $$Y=X\mathbf 1_{X\in[0,1[}$$ by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to reckon with here:

1) The distribution of $X$ is a bit weird.

As you write, the probability of $X$ landing in the half open interval $[0, 1[$ is $1/2$. However we can distinguish two events here:

A: $X$ lands exactly at $0$

B: $X$ lands in the open interval $]0, 1[$

Can you compute the probability of each?

2) $Y = 0$ whenever $X < 0$ **but also** whenever $X \geq 1$. This means that when computing $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t)$ for any $t \geq 0$ we should take into account both these rather different ways in which $Y$ can be $0$ and hence $\leq t$.

I think with these hints you can reverse engineer how the correction model found its counter-intuitive answer. But if not, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood ! :D